# How to retrieve data from a url in python and then send it to the file from which i can work on that data below is how i retrieve data

Tags: python, django, api

How to retrieve data from a url in python and then send it to the file from which I can work on that data. Below is how I retrieve data

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import urllib

def indexx(request):
    url ="http://##########/query?condition=%s&key=e25c7 &op=json"
    condition ='aaaaa'
    x = urllib.urlopen(url%condition)
    y=HttpResponse(x.read())
    return(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need all of this. Do yourself a favor and use the awesome library [`python-requests`](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

From the linked documentation, you can do all of it rather easily:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

You can also write all of the content into file, if you want. But you should really be writing it into memory that can be saved to disk using SQLite or Redis.